# retrieving String as int in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am storing `sub_topic_id`s` as 200,201,202(in single column) in my requirement table

When I have to show the requirement, I need to get the `sub_topic_name` of subject from subjects table and show the description.

The current query I am using,

```
 select sub_topic_name 
 from sub_topics 
 where sub_topic_id in (a.subject)) as subject from requirement_table,
```

I get only the first id`s name.....

Comment: Storing in *single column* or *single row*? What is the data type of the column you are storing this values into?

Comment: is `sub_topic_id` same as `a.subject`???

Comment: Storing in one column and no. I am storing subtopic id`s (comma seperated) in a single column in subject table and subtopics table have the reference to those ids with subtopic name as description.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sub_topic_name from sub_topics where sub_topic_id in

 (select sub_topic_id from requirement)
```